# Trouble sending Uint8List from Flutter to Android[Java] using method channels

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, flutter-method-channel

I have a method channel setup on Flutter to send Uint8List to Android[Java]. Android is receiving the data but it looks like the bytes are getting wrapped at 127.

Ex: if I send [254, 100, 32] from flutter, it shows up as [-2, 100, 32] in Android.

Basically, any value in the list over 127 is getting converted to a negative value.

Here is how I have the method channel setup on the Fluter side:

```
static const MethodChannel platform = MethodChannel(SEND_SERIAL_MESSAGE_TO_ANDROID);

Future<void> sendMessageToAndroid(List<int> message) async {

  final bool result = await platform.invokeMethod('parseMessage', message);
}
```

And this is how I am receiving it on the Android side

```
@Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler(
                    (call, result) -> {
                        if (call.method.equals("parseMessage")) {
                            byte[] message = call.arguments();
                            parseMessage(message);
                        } else {
                            result.notImplemented();
                        }
                    }

            );
}

private void parseMessage(byte[] message){
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, message.toString());
}
```

Question: how do I stop values over 127 in my Uint8List from getting converted to a negative value in Java?

Let me know if you need to see any more of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before I start explaining what happened let me show you something in dart first

```
Uint8List li = Uint8List.fromList([-2, 100, 32]);
li.cast<int>();
print(li); //prints [254, 100, 32]
```

so why -2 changed to positive 254? short explaining would be that dart expect the bytes in **Uint8List to be Unsigned values** so it prints the positive value 254 but still they are just bytes,

on the contrary in java the default is **Signed bytes**, and it doesn't care how it prints bytes because they are still bytes so I can tell you happily that is nothing wrong with your code, **the actual problem** that you tried to see the bytes value through printing the byte list,
another sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609437/11252816
, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609516/11252816